# Increment some columns of multiple rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am trying to update multiple columns of a set of rows simultaneously. (in my case I have the same number of columns and the number of rows -- I'm making a similarity matrix, but generally speaking, this shouldn't be important). Is there a way to do this more efficiently than my examples below? -- I'm open to using `python lists`, `pandas` or `numpy`; doesn't really matter; as long as it's the fastest.

**Example 1 - Two nested `for` loops**

```
adj_mat = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]])
inlier_mask = np.array([False, False, False, True, True, True, False, 
False, False])
inlier_idx = np.array(np.nonzero(inlier_mask))[0].tolist()

for i in inlier_idx:
    for j in inlier_idx:
        adj_mat[i,j] += 1

print(adj_mat)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 2 2 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]]
```

**Example 2 - Only one `for` loop**

```
adj_mat = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]])
inlier_mask = np.array([False, False, False, True, True, True, False, 
False, False])
inlier_idx = np.array(np.nonzero(inlier_mask))[0].tolist()

for i in inlier_idx:
    adj_mat[i,inlier_idx] += 1
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 2 2 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]]
```

Is there a solution such as: `adj_mat[inlier_idx,inlier_idx] += 1` that can achieve this with no loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to create two broadcastable indexing arrays and then index and add -

```
adj_mat[np.ix_(inlier_idx, inlier_idx)] += 1
# or adj_mat[np.ix_(inlier_mask, inlier_mask)] += 1
```

Alternatively, we can manually create the `broadcastable` arrays with extending `inlier_idx` to `2D` with `None/np.newaxis` -

```
inlier_idx = np.flatnonzero(inlier_mask)
adj_mat[inlier_idx[:,None], inlier_idx] += 1
```